# Unable to change font color via class, only works using the ID attribute

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

I am teaching myself Ruby on Rails and I am absolutely loving it so far. I am not sure if this is an issue specific to Rails or not. I am unable to change the "color" attribute through a class, only an ID. I am able to change other attributes such as background-color using a class, but not color.

```
#topLink {
  color: #fff;
}
```

The above code will work, but the below code doesn't..

```
.topLink {
  color: #fff;
}
```

This is my html code

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "Game Week", root_path, id: "logo" %>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Home",   root_path, id: "topLink" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Help",   help_path, class: "topLink" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Log in", '#', id: "topLink" %></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container"> <a id="logo" href="/">Game Week</a>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a class="topLink" href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/help">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Log in</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

The first `<li>` tag will change color because it's assigned an ID. The second `<li>` tag doesn't do anything because it's assigned a class.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the rendered HTML?

Comment: <li><a id="topLink" href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="topLink" href="/help">Help</a></li>

Comment: Works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/pffrkcbd/

Comment: @JacobGray I just showed my friend, he said it is because I have bootstrap enabled in the gemfile, which will override my custom CSS with bootstraps CSS.

Comment: If your css files are all being included from application.css, in the stylesheets directory (usually via require_tree ., but can also be manual) then you have to remember that they are included in alphabetical order and also the order they are placed in your application.css file.  If you want things to appear in a different order you can rename the files... 01-framework.css, 02-site-styles.css... or whatever they're called, so you can choose the override order.  If you sitll have quoestions, post your application.css and list the names of the files in the directory

Answer (score 0):

I think if you understand CSS Specificity, you'll be more comfortable debugging such problems. Give [this MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) a read.

There is a lot of caveats in css specificity, but generally you need to understand that **id** overrides **class** and a selector with a class and an element, e.g. `.nav a` overrides a single class selector `.topLink`. ([Here](https://specificity.keegan.st/) is a fun CSS calculator you can play with).

My guess is that there is some bootstrap rule for a link inside nav, which overrides your single class selector rule. Another tip, **the last selector that is loaded overrides previous ones if they are of equal weight**. So as pointed out by @trh in a comment, you probably want to require bootstrap library BEFORE you require your custom css files.

Otherwise, using more specific selectors is guaranteed to work in your case. Just don't use **id** for css styling as it is considered bad practice (See MDN article for more info on that).

Answer (score 0):

try this simple trick and see if it works

```
.topLink {color: #fff !important;}
```

it'll over ride all the parent class properties.. .